# How to read a certain line from a text file in Python

Tags: python, text

I have a Python file and a text file with about 1000 names in it. I opened this file in Python, like this

`names = open('names.txt', 'r')`

the text file is laid out as follows:

```
Jason
Drake
Larry
```

How can I print the name 'Drake' onto the screen?

I know this question was answered previously, but I couldn't understand the explanations, as they were advanced. Please explain in an easy to understand manner, as I am new to programming.

Answer (score 0):

```
names = open('names.txt', 'r')       # open the text file
namesList = names.read().split('\n') # read the entire file and split into a list
print(namesList[1])                  # print the element at index 1
names.close()                        # close the text file
```

Output:

> Drake

If you are after just one line answer because you are going to read just one name:

```
print(open('names.txt', 'r').read().split('\n')[1])
```

That might be an expensive thing to do, if you are doing it over and over again tho.

In either case, if you are using CPython, garbage collector will take care of closing the file. If you are using some other implementation and you're not sure about that, you may use `with`:

```
with open('names.txt', 'r') as names:
    namesList = names.read().split('\n')
    print(namesList[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('names.txt') as names:
    names = names.read()
    names = names.split()
    print(names[1])
```

The first line opens the file in the variable `names`

The second line converts the file into text.

The third line splits the text into a list, with the contents of each line being a new element.

The fourth line prints the name.
Note that in Python, the first number is 0, so if you wanted to access the first name in the list it would be `names[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

Just look for `Drake` specifically and print it out:

```
to_find = 'Drake'

with open('names.txt') as file:
    for line in map(str.strip, file):
        if line == to_find:
            print(line)
```

Which Outputs:

```
Drake
```